# WindowManager$BadTokenException when showing AlertDialog on Android 7

Tags: java, android

Google Play shows a lot of crash reports caused by WindowManager$BadTokenException.

Full log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3344)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21 (ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1583)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:779)
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:679)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:329)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show (AlertDialog.java:1112)
    at com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.activities.SyncthingActivity.showLoadingDialog (SyncthingActivity.java:142)
    at com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.activities.SyncthingActivity.onApiChange (SyncthingActivity.java:88)
    at com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.activities.SyncthingActivity.access$lambda$1 (SyncthingActivity.java)
    at com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.activities.SyncthingActivity$$Lambda$2.onApiChange (Unknown Source)
    at com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.service.SyncthingService.onApiChange (SyncthingService.java:530)
    at com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.service.SyncthingService.updateState (SyncthingService.java:246)
    at com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.service.SyncthingService.onStartCommand (SyncthingService.java:181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3327)
```

Relevant code:

```
if (isFinishing() || mLoadingDialog != null)
    return;

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, null);
TextView loadingText = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading_text);
loadingText.setText((getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_FIRST_START, false))
        ? R.string.web_gui_creating_key
        : R.string.api_loading);

mLoadingDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setView(dialogLayout)
        .show();
```

What could be the cause of this crash? It would also help if I had a way to reproduce the crash. The full source of the app is [available on Github](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nutomic/syncthingandroid/activities/SyncthingActivity.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem. In my code I was doing something like this (in a much more complicated way):

```
if (isFinishing())
    return;
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).show();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

The show() method call finished normally, but the dialog was only attached to the Activity after the sleep was finished. So if you have this problem, make sure you're not doing any long-running operation on the main thread.

Comment: @NullPointerException I moved the blocking operation to a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem might occur if the app is closing, or is in the background somehow.
You should check if your activity is not being closed (for example, onDestroy was called), and that it is active in the foreground (and visible).

There are several options for how to check if it is in the background, here's one that should work:

```
RunningAppProcessInfo myProcess = new RunningAppProcessInfo();
ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(myProcess);
isInBackground = myProcess.importance != RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help at all, the crashes are still occuring. Btw I just noticed that the crashes appear on all Android versions, Google Play was just listing them seperately for different versions.

Comment: This is good news for you that it happens for all versions - it means you should be able to reproduce it. I gave you my best best - I suggest you try to reproduce it while playing with the app and sending it to background, while you are in debug mode with a break point in the relevant code.